# Cant get value of vars to create a form dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This html file is were the form is going to be create in the "div" with the "id=form". The vars are defined in the html file

```
<body>
    <script> 
        var types=['text','number', 'text'];
        var fields=3;
        var temas =3;
        var fieldsM=['um','dois', 'tres'];
    </script>
    <div id="main">
```

This button calls the function of the js file that creates the form

```
        <button class="button" onclick="gerar();" id="gerar">Criar Novo</button>
        <div id="form">  
            <!--form here -->
        </div>   
    </div>
</body>
```

I have this Js file were the form is being created but when i call the function "Gerar" the placeholder appears undefined. This function creates a form and then with the numbers of "Temas" creates a "div" and inside that div creates "fields value" inputs elements.

```
function gerar(){ 
    f = document.createElement("form");
    f.setAttribute('method',"post");
    f.setAttribute('action',"");

    for(var i=0;i<parent.temas; i++){ 
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute('id', "form"+i);

        for(var j=0;j<parent.fields;j++){ 
            i = document.createElement("input");
            i.setAttribute('type', parent.types[i]);
            i.setAttribute('placeholder', parent.fieldsM[i]);
            f.appendChild(i);
            div.appendChild(f);
        }
    }
document.getElementById('form').appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: For what reason you are using `parent.temas` instead of calling it directly `temas`?

Comment: What is the `parent.fieldsM[i]` value when you stop on that said variable?

Comment: Because those variables are going to be filled with a prompt to the user and have to be created in the html file so then when i call a function to populate those variables, the value be stored there. "parent.temas" is a way of accessing them

Comment: @JPeter the value appears undefined, but in the console log when i right parent.fieldsM[i] the array appears correct

Comment: @LuisLuisMaiaMaia well for a well writed code you could use `parent.fieldsM.length` to know the size of array here `for(var j=0;j<parent.fields;j++){ `. Did you try concatenate with a String ? `i.setAttribute('placeholder', (parent.fieldsM[i]+""));`

Comment: @JPete I just tried and the it still appears undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set var `parent` to be a reference to the global `window`.

After that you need to take care with your `for` loop:
 You define inside the first `for` that

 `var i = 0`
 then below, inside the second `for` you say:
`i = document.createElement("input");`
 Now, when you try to access, for example, `parent.types[i]`, `i` isn't a number anymore, it is now an element... so it will not work... define another variable to be that element, in my example below I used `x`

```js
var parent = window;

var types=['text','number', 'text'];
var fields=3;
var temas =3;
var fieldsM=['um','dois', 'tres'];

function gerar(){ 
  var f = document.createElement("form");
  f.setAttribute('method',"post");
  f.setAttribute('action',"");

  for(var i=0; i < parent.temas; i++){ 
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute('id', "form"+i);

    for(var j=0; j < parent.fields; j++){ 
      var x = document.createElement("input");
      x.setAttribute('type', parent.types[i]);
      x.setAttribute('placeholder', parent.fieldsM[i]);

      f.appendChild(x);
      div.appendChild(f);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('form').appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="gerar();" id="gerar">Criar Novo</button>
<div id="main">
  <div id="form">  
        <!--form here -->
  </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an object (e.g.: `parent`) to directly access globally-defined variables (`var ...`), then there are two options:

1. Let `parent` be a reference to the global object.

   ```
   var parent = window
   ```
2. Let `parent` reference the globally-defined variables as properties.

   ```
   var parent = {
       count: fields, // => 3
       $fields: fieldsM, // => ['username', 'email', 'password']
       $types: typesM, // => ['text', 'email', 'password']
       terms: temas /* and so on so forth... */
   }
   ```

But make sure your variables are global for this to work.

On a side note, I'd say it's better practice to have those variables (`temas`, `fields`, `fieldsM`, ...) local & private while having a variable (`parent`) that is global accessing them.

If it`s still not working out, you could try this out:

```
/* Function to create new <form> element */
function createForm(id) {
    // Create your form manager -- to manage all things form-related,
    // you can also declare this outside the `createForm` function.
    let formManager = {
        fieldCount: 3, // no. of fields
        fields: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'], // the fields` placeholders
        formCount: 3, // no. of forms
        types: ['text', 'number', 'text'] // the fields` types
    },
        // The form
        form = document.createElement('form');

    // Modify the form
    form.action = '';
    arguments.length && (form.id = String(id));
    form.method = 'post';

    // Iterate over the no. of forms
    for (let i = 0; i < formManager.formCount; i += 1) {
        // Make a new <div>
        let div = document.createElement('div');

        // Modify the <div>
        div.id = 'formContainer_' + i;

        // Iterate over the no. of fields
        for (let j = 0; j < formManager.fieldCount; j += 1) {
            // Make a new <input>
            let input = document.createElement('input');

            // Modify the <input>
            input.placeholder = formManager.fields[j];
            input.type = formManager.types[j];

            // Insert the <input> into the <div>
            div.appendChild(input)
        }

        // Insert the <div> into the <form>
        form.appendChild(div)
    }

    // Return your new <form> element
    return form
};

// Make a new form
createForm();

// Make a <form> with ID: `LapysForm`
createForm('LapysForm')
```

The `createForm` function returns a `<form>` element as you specified to be created. You can then append the form as you want.

Comment: I tried and put the variables locally but even then when i called them to be the "placeholder" attribute and the "type"  they still appear undefined

Comment: There were a few logic errors I found when I got time to look at the code carefully, so I tried to rebuild you question in the edit I made to my answer.